# Get users Manager using Client API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-hosted-app, rest

`url: appweburl + "_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='" + seluser + "'"`,

For my SP 2013 app I need to get a users manager and I'm using the following code to achieve this:

```
function getusersManager(selUser) {
//clear any errors
var errModalArea = document.getElementById("modalAnnouncements");
// Remove all nodes from the errAllEvents <DIV> so we have a clean space to write to
while (errModalArea.hasChildNodes()) {
    errModalArea.removeChild(errModalArea.lastChild);
}
var seluser = selUser;
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl.toLowerCase());
executor.executeAsync({
   url: appweburl + "_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='" + seluser + "'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: successGetUserManager,
    error: errorGetEmployee

});
}

function successGetUserManager(data) {
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
var announcementsHTML = "";
document.getElementById("renderAnnouncements").innerHTML = "<b> Hello " + jsonObject.d.Manager;

//$('#txtManger').val(jsonObject.d.Manager);
}
```

However this keeps returning a "undefined". Putting the call directly into the browser using

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v=%27i:0%23.f|membership|xxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com%27
```

Gives me back the correct data but I'm unsure how to get that value...I see no key etc?

```
<d:GetUserProfilePropertyFor xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">i:0#.f|membership|xxx@xxx.com</d:GetUserProfilePropertyFor>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this url:

```
appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Manager')?@v='" + seluser + "'&@target='" + encodeURIComponent(hostweburl) + "'"
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927(v=office.15).aspx) link has more on the cross-domain library, `SP.RequestExecutor.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in my environment.

**My script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var loginName = "domain\username";


function GetCurrentUser() {

var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Office')?@v=" + "'" + loginName + "'";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };


$.ajax({

  url : requestUri,

  method: "GET",

  headers : requestHeaders,

  success : onSuccess,

  error : onError

});

}


function onSuccess(data){


  var department = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;

  alert(department);


} 

function onError(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){

alert("Error: " + jqxr.responseText)

}

GetCurrentUser();  

});
```

I think the important part is:

```
var department = data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor;
alert(department);
```

And my variable loginname with %5C (\) and %2E (.)
encodeURIComponent() doesn't help me here because of (\) and (.)

```
domain%5Clastname%2Efirstname
```

You can check out my whole script with "get the current User" and pass the loginname to the next function here: http://1drv.ms/1enskYR where I finally change a link on the page to the users department.

Hopefully my english isn't that bad...

Answer (score 0):

```
**<script src="../SiteAssets/JQUERY/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script> 
<script>

var RESTURL = "https://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i%3A0%23%2Ew%7Cdomain%5Cloginname'";
$(document).ready(function () {

    GetUserInformation();

});

function GetUserInformation()

{

 var self = this;

 $.ajax({

  url: RESTURL,

  type: "GET",

  headers: {

   "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",

  },

  success: function (userdata) {

    var department= userdata.d.UserProfileProperties.results[11].Value;
    var manager=userdata.d.UserProfileProperties.results[15].Value;
     alert(Department+"  "+manager);
     alert(userdata.d.Title);

  },

  error: function (error) {

   alert(JSON.stringify(error));

  }

 });



}

 </script> 
    </script>**
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was having my username in this format that solved my issue:

```
domain%5Clastname%2Efirstname
```